# DataContract with inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, datacontract, known-types

I have a class with a list of objects that is serialized and deserialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class Manager
{
  [DataMember]
  public BigBase[] enemies;
}
```

The class with subclasses:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Medium))]
[KnownType(typeof(Small))]
public class BigBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool isMoving;
}
[DataContract]
public class Medium : BigBase
{
}
[DataContract]
public class Small: BigBase
{
}
```

Now whats strange when deserializing the enemies array will contain correctly deserialized BigBase classes but each Medium and Small class doesnt have the correct value for isMoving.

Comment: Without some sample **test code** I doubt that someone will want to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `KnownType` attribute on `Manager`:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Medium))]
[KnownType(typeof(Small))]
public class Manager
{
  [DataMember]
  public BigBase[] enemies;
}
```

Because it's the Manager which has an array of `BigBase` whose elements might be the derived classes as well. So the `DataContractSerializer` will know what to expect from the array when serializing and deserializing `Manager` object (and it's all `DataMember`).

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract]
public class Medium : BigBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UpgradedName;
}
```

I dont see that in this test Code. I think your serialization code is wrong.

Sample calls:

```
Manager test = new Manager();

            Medium medium = new Medium() {isMoving = true,Name = "medium", UpgradedName = "mediaum name"};
            //some items in array
            test.enemies = new BigBase[] {medium,new Small{isMoving = false},new Small{isMoving = true}, new BigBase {Name = "bigbase", isMoving = true}, new BigBase {Name = "bigbase2", isMoving = true}, new BigBase {Name = "bigbase3", isMoving = true}} ;

            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Manager));
            FileStream writer = new FileStream("test123.txt", FileMode.Create);
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, test);
            writer.Close();
            writer = new FileStream("test123.txt", FileMode.Open);
            Manager deserializedmanager = serializer.ReadObject(writer) as Manager;
            //verify serialized object
            Console.WriteLine("medium object:"+ (deserializedmanager.enemies[0]  as Medium).UpgradedName);
```